# How do you draw a Control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drawing, gdi+

How do you *draw* a control?

I'm not talking about UserControl/Custom Control (or am I?), but I am talking about using GDI to draw my own custom shape, and give it properties and events, like `myNotSoStraightThickLine.Clicked`, or `myNotSoStraightThickLine.Color`, etc.

How do you make things that you've drawn with GDI+ clickable, selectable, movable, with events and properties that other controls inherit, as well as making it Disposable whenever needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to draw each thing that you want, and capture mouse move events and mouse click events to determine whether you have clicked a part of each element. Which will get tricky if you are dealing with diagonals and ellipses, you may have to determine a full list of possible x + y coordinates (on a per pixel basis) for each of your elements possible positions on creation and compare those on the mouse move/click events.

And as for recording colours, you could get the properties of the PictureBox content at the location of your move/click event, or perhaps it would be better to same some objects with a mirror of the properties of the controls that you are drawing, that way you could actually  create your objects and then take their properties for drawing them, which could be simpler.